# Alternative to using Wildcard in WPF Pack URI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently working on refactoring the resource structure in my app. (Windows Desktop WPF)

Up until now I used a single `Icons.xaml` file to store all my icons as xaml-vector drawings. But over time the file got really cluttered and I now want to split it into multiple files. Each containing a group of icons, grouping variants of the same icon together. (For example: `Lock.xaml` containing icons for an *open* and *closed* lock icon)

While merging these files into a single resource dictionary again in my `Icons.xaml`

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Icons/Log.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Icons/Disconnect.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Icons/Accept.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Icons/Lock.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        (...)
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I noticed that it would be so much easier and cleaner if pack URIs would simply support a wildcard inside the source parameter. So I coud include all `*.xaml` inside the icons folder with a single line.

Sadly by reading through the [pack uri docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#the-pack-uri-scheme) I haven't read anything about wildcards or something similar.

So now I'm wondering if there are alternative ways which would enable me to merge all `*.xaml` files inside a specific directory (all including only one resource dictionary each) into a single resource dictionary without specifying each file explicitly.

Or do I just have to accept that each time I add a new `Icons/Something.xaml` I will have to manually add the line to merge it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or do I just have to accept that each time I add a new Icons/Something.xaml I will have to manually add the line to merge it?

Yes. It's either that or write some C# code that checks for all files in a specific folder at runtime and creates the resource dictionaries to be merged programmatically.

XAML has no support for doing this. It's a markup language.